# Getting the authenticated username to a function view in django

Tags: python, django

Im trying to modify the current user's data but with no sucess, need some help.

```
def account_admin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        mod_form = ModificationForm(request.POST)
        if mod_form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.get(request.user)
            user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password1'])
            user.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            user.save
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/register/success/')
    else:
        mod_form = ModificationForm()

    variables = RequestContext(request, {
        'mod_form': mod_form
    })
    return render_to_response('registration/account.html', variables)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
user = User.objects.get(request.user)
```

Ideally, it would have been

```
user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
```

You dont need a query to retrieve the user object here, since `request.user` evaluates to an instance of the logged in user object.

```
user = request.user
user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password1'])
user.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
user.save()
```

Should work

Also, make sure you have the [`@login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator to the `account_admin` method

Comment: wow, i had this real security issue that the @login_required solves... without it anyone could type the users address on the browser and access its account without logging in.

Answer (score 2):

`request.user` is already an instance of User, there's no point in doing another query.

Plus, you actually need to *call* `save()`.

Comment: Both of you were right, i will post the working code has soon has this thing allows me, i have to wait  8 hours. :(

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have you answer from the above posts but I notice that you did not authenticate the user (you may have done it elsewhere that I don't know about). In case you want to do so, try the login_reqired decorator https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required

Comment: Hi Conan Li, thanks for the response, indeed the user only uses this function if authenticated. After user's makes the login an option named "manage account" appears, so he has to be loged in order to evoke this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much karthikr and Daniel! Heres how i got it to work:

```
def account_admin(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    mod_form = ModificationForm(request.POST)
    if mod_form.is_valid():
        user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        user.set_password(mod_form.cleaned_data['password1'])
        user.email = mod_form.cleaned_data['email']
        user.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/register/success/')
else:
    mod_form = ModificationForm()

variables = RequestContext(request, {
    'mod_form': mod_form
})
return render_to_response('registration/account.html', variables)

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

karthikr, iam still learning django, i dont get your sugestion of the decorator @login_required. What does it do?

Comment: Hey i already searched  @login_required, i've posted a comment above.
Thanks to karthikr, is reply was truly helpful.

Comment: You can safely replace `user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)` with `user=request.user` - It is essentially fetching the same object.

Comment: I tried that before and it didn’t work... I think its because it doesn't give user name as a string... perhaps if i ad this code to the user model:
def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user